# Java Implementation of T first() method to class Hashset<T>

Tags: java, data-structures

I am having difficulty with the following exercise. I do not know which way to approach it. I know I should use some sort of iteration but I am unsure. I have been able to implement the T first() method with a binary search tree but not with a HashSet.

`Add the following method to class HashSet<T> and write a suitable test program.
T first()
// least value in the set (if the set is empty
// throws NoSuchElementException)`

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.Iterable;

 class HashSet<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> { 

  private LinkedSet<T>[] hashTable; // hash table


HashSet() { // create the empty set
    hashTable = (LinkedSet<T>[])(new LinkedSet[1000]); 
                                              // note coding trick!     
    for (int i=0; i<hashTable.length; i++)
        hashTable[i] = new LinkedSet<T>();  

    //Exercise 1
    int numItems = 0;
    for (LinkedSet<T> miniSet: hashTable)
        numItems = numItems+miniSet.size();


}




private int hash(T t) { // hash t into hashTable index
    return Math.abs(t.hashCode()%hashTable.length);
}

int size() {    
    int numItems = 0;
    for (LinkedSet<T> miniSet: hashTable)
        numItems = numItems+miniSet.size();
    return numItems;
}

boolean contains(T t) { 
    return hashTable[hash(t)].contains(t);
}

boolean add(T t) { 
    return hashTable[hash(t)].add(t);
} 

boolean remove(T t) {
    return hashTable[hash(t)].remove(t);
}

//Exercise 3

  public Iterator<T> iterator() { 
    ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (LinkedSet<T> ls: hashTable)
        for (T t: ls) items.add(t);
    return items.iterator();
}   





  boolean addAll(HashSet<T> ts){
    boolean changed = false;
    for(T i : ts)
        if(add(i))
            changed =true;
    return true;
    // add all elements of ts to set; ts is unchanged.

    }





}

import java.util.Iterator;




 public class Prog {

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T first(HashSet<T> hs)
    // least value in the set (if the set is empty
   // throws NoSuchElementException
     {
      T least = null;

      for(T i : hs){
      if (i.compareTo(least)<0){
        i = least;
      }

     }
      return least;
    }

import java.util.List;


  public class main1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashSet<String> test1 = new HashSet<String>();
    test1.add("sean");
    test1.add("adam");
    test1.add("ava");

    HashSet<Integer> test2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    test2.add(2);
    test2.add(10);
    test2.add(5);

    System.out.println(test1.size());

    System.out.println(Prog.first(test2));


   }

 }
```

Comment: HashSet isn't ordered and has no concept of a "least" value. You could just return the first value returned by `iterator()` but this is an arbitrary choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- iterate through values: try for ( T x: the_set) ...
- take the min: take the first, an iterate, and if new is less, take it
- return that value (or exception if no value)

try to complete this

```
public static <T> T first(HashSet<T> _ht)
{
// if _ht empty throws an exception
// TODO

// Take the first (or any element)
// TODO
T least; 

for (T one_element: _ht)
  {
    // compare one_element and least
    // TODO 
    // and keep the least !
  }

return least;
}
```

Comment: If I am to iterate through the values will I not need to pass the set name to the method. T first()

Comment: I was trying to test my implementation. I have a problem with my iterator. public Iterator<T> iterator() { 
  ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();
  for (LinkedSet<T> ls: hashTable)
   for (T t: ls) items.add(t);
  return items.iterator();
 }

Comment: It gives me the errorException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at HashSet.iterator(HashSet.java:60)
 at Prog.first(Prog.java:14)
 at main1.main(main1.java:20)

Comment: could you please put your code, formatted, in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment from Peter, a `HashSet` has no concept of "first" or "last", since it's not ordered. However, there is the class [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), which implements `SortedSet`.

The element type must define a natural order (e.g. `int`, or `Comparable<T>`), or otherwise you have to provide a `Comparator<T>` to the constructor of the tree set.

Example:

```
Integer[] numbers = { 5, 9, 1, 11 };
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
Integer least = set.first();  // 1
```

---

One possible implementation of the `first()` method (assuming a binary tree):

```
public T first() {
    Node<T> p = root;
    if (p != null) {
        while (p.left != null) {  // not "while (p != null)"
            p = p.left;
        }
    }
    return p == null ? null : p.item;
}
```

Comment: In one of my treeset exercises I have the same method implemented. Is this correct?  T first(){
    Node <T> p = root;
    while(p !=(null)){
     p = p.left;
     }
    
    return (p.item);

Comment: @Scolgo: Looks like `p` is always gonna be `null`. I updated my answer.